# How do I need to configure my site on AWS with Elastic Load Balancing to force HTTPS everywhere?

Tags: 8

my site is up and running, but all my form submits get redirected to an http:// link. The redirect from http to https on my Server (Apache on EC2) is configured and you don't see any effect as a user. If i create baseurls directly on the server it also returns http:// links.

It causes troubles on the intern side:

- Google Analytics can't track this redirects as the same user and sees every form submit as an new user from a direct source.
- the redirect causes a delay for the user (mostly millisecs)

Config:

- running an Drupal 8.7.7 on an Apache Server.
- http-redirect:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

- settings.php:

```
  $settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
  $settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['PROXY_ADDRESS']);

  $settings['reverse_proxy_trusted_headers'] = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

This config for setting.php was introduced in 8.7.0:
https://www.drupal.org/node/3030558

I really don't have any clue what to do now, since i tried like thousands of possibilities.

Best Regards 
FirstSanny

Answer (score 1):

Got it myself.

Configuration is absolutly correct, but i set the wrong reverse_proxy_adresses to be allowed. I thought, that i can use the beanstalk-url, but it worked perfectly fine with one of the internal IP Configs for AWS: 172.16.0.0/12